# equivalent of mysql CURRENT_DATE() function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Hi i'm inserting a date entry into a field that has a Type Timestamp and field default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ...my insert value will look like this

```
'.($data[16] == '' ? CURRENT_DATE() : $data[16]).'
```

how would I format the CURRENT_DATE() to be 30-Nov-10 to match what $data[16] format would be if not present. Also should I change the Field Type to Date and not Timestamp?

Comment: php doesn't have such a function.

Comment: Who upvoted this lame question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date($format,strtotime(CURRENT_DATE))` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

`CURRENT_DATE()` is a MySQL function. You could use it as a string literal:

```
$sql_date = ($date == '') ?
  "DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%d-%b-%y')" : "'$date'";

mysql_query("UPDATE foo SET date=$sql_date");
```

This assumes that `$date` is safe for SQL insertion.

Or you could just use PHP:

```
if (!$date) $date = date('%d-%M-%y');  
mysql_query("UPDATE foo SET date='$date'");
```

Personally, I would generally use the PHP solution as it makes it easier to use the same query with the same safe parameter placeholders (not used in this example) regardless of how you build the date.

> Also should I change the Field Type to Date and not Timestamp

If the time is irrelevant, then it should be a date field. However, if it's a date/timestamp field (and not a text field), you should be inserting in the YYYY-MM-DD format, and the above code is useless.

That is, if the field is text, then the above code could be useful. However, if you are storing simply a date into a single field, you should use a date field, In that case, the format you insert should always be in YYYY-MM-DD. When you *retrieve* the data, you can format it in the way you want for display.

Answer (score 0):

Well without any further information
all i can tell you is

you should look into the function [date](http://php.net/date) and it's second arg
where you put a timestamp which you could create with [mktime](http://php.net/mktime) alt. [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't make sense.. I'm assuming you want to output the current date.. in which case you can change the format with the following:

```
$today = date("M/d/y");
```

also, time() will output the current date to the second in a unix timestamp

```
$today = time();
```